# QGIS 3.34 and nested GeoJSONs

Tags: qgis-3, geojson

Is there an issue with how QGIS 3.34 ingests GeoJSONs that were exported by Kili with nested attributes?
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
[
[
-117.58436016300587,
37.7667430227738
],
[
-117.58441399719088,
37.76801954529419
],
[
-117.58538301252105,
37.7679769948985
],
[
-117.58538301252105,
37.76695577805737
],
[
-117.58436016300587,
37.7667430227738
]
]
]
},
"id": "20231211133829869-800",
"properties": {
"kili": {
"children": {

```
                },
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "name": "ACTIVE_SITE"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "polygon",
                "job": "OBJECT_DETECTION_JOB"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -117.58464380341776,
                        37.77076393451066
                    ],
                    [
                        -117.58464380341776,
                        37.77182785035533
                    ],
                    [
                        -117.58603799080811,
                        37.77194184043074
                    ],
                    [
                        -117.58579761367182,
                        37.770839929007224
                    ],
                    [
                        -117.58464380341776,
                        37.77076393451066
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "id": "20231211133834163-801",
        "properties": {
            "kili": {
                "children": {

                },
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "name": "ACTIVE_SITE"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "polygon",
                "job": "OBJECT_DETECTION_JOB"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        -117.58811382540193,
                        37.78161288519987
                    ],
                    [
                        -117.58833984975695,
                        37.78464929737632
                    ],
                    [
                        -117.59007270314564,
                        37.78458976108167
                    ],
                    [
                        -117.59014804459731,
                        37.78143426883418
                    ],
                    [
                        -117.58811382540193,
                        37.78161288519987
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "id": "20231211133848694-803",
        "properties": {
            "kili": {
                "children": {

                },
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "name": "INACTIVE_INACTIVE_0"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "polygon",
                "job": "OBJECT_DETECTION_JOB"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

I need to be able to plot the polygons and have the attributes for the active and inactive sites differentiated, but when I ingest the geojson into QGIS 3.34 and run the classification routine with "kili" as the value the polygons are not classified correctly - no difference. When the geojson is ingested into QGIS 3.14 and the classification routine is applied with "kili" as a value the program goes through the nests into the categories and I can toggle between active sites and inactive sites.

It there an issue on how QGIS 3.34 reads in complex, nested geojson files?